# Shearing a group of objects

Tags: transforms

[[image: transformed group of objects]][3][image: Initial Object][![transformed object][3]][3]I have a group of objects and I need to give them all an equal shear  during an animation (like a matrix transformation).I tried using the lattice. It does distorts it(like a shearing) but it does not give an equal shear to all the objects.

The first image is of the object that I wish to transform. 
The second image is of the object after it has been transformed but the objects itself seems to have become separate and this is not how a matrix transformation operates mathematically. Please help me to understand what is the lattice deform transformation doing and how to use it such that it is in accordance with matrix transformation.

Comment: Could you post some screenshots of what you currently have and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Lattice Deformation should do what you want. Is it possible to post the blend-file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that if the lattice encloses the objects completely and if the options are changed from bspline to linear, it does the job.